Generate JSON text with a column that holds int array
I asked ChatGPT this question:
How to generate a JSON text like this
{
    "CategoryId": 100,
    "AccountId": 200,
    "ItemIds": [12, 13, 14, 15],
    "Created": "2024-10-23",
    "SiteId": 111,
    "PriorityLevel": 2
} 

in SQL Server using T-SQL?
And the answer I got:
WITH ItemList AS 
(
    SELECT 12 AS ItemId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 13 AS ItemId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 14 AS ItemId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 15 AS ItemId
)
SELECT 
    100 AS CategoryId,
    200 AS AccountId,
    (SELECT ItemId FROM ItemList FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS ItemIds,
    '2024-10-23' AS Created,
    111 AS SiteId,
    2 AS PriorityLevel
FOR 
    JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;

It said that it would produce outcome, which is exactly what I wanted, as shown below:
{
    "CategoryId": 100,
    "AccountId": 200,
    "ItemIds": [12, 13, 14, 15],
    "Created": "2024-10-23",
    "SiteId": 111,
    "PriorityLevel": 2
}

But it actually produced this when I executed the sample query:
{
    "CategoryId": 100,
    "AccountId": 200,
    "ItemIds": "{\"ItemId\":12},{\"ItemId\":13},{\"ItemId\":14},{\"ItemId\":15}",
    "Created": "2024-10-23",
    "SiteId": 111,
    "PriorityLevel": 2
}

How to get the ItemIds to be "ItemIds": [12, 13, 14, 15] instead of "ItemIds":"{\"ItemId\":12},{\"ItemId\":13},{\"ItemId\":14},{\"ItemId\":15} which threw a deserializer exception when I tried to de-serialize the JSON message to a class that expects ItemIds as int[] in C# ?

What language are you after a solution in here? You have tagged both T-SQL and C#.

It's a very different question, but I demonstrate how to in this answer.

Wait, do you mean you didn't get correct answer from chatgpt? How can lowly stackoverflow users help you then? The problem is that sql server doesn't support pure json arrays generation (except some preview version maybe), so usually one uses string_agg or other functions to generate json as string manually

@ThomA I just noticed that you already answered my question before I posted the answer to my own question based on what our internal DBA showed me. Thanks a lot, and I did mark your answer there as Helpful.

With help from internal DBA, I got the issue resolved by using json_query() and string_agg() functions.
The correct query should be:
WITH ItemList AS (
    SELECT 12 AS ItemId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 13 AS ItemId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 14 AS ItemId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 15 AS ItemId
)
SELECT 
    100 AS CategoryId,
    200 AS AccountId,
    (SELECT json_query('[' + string_agg(ItemId,',')+ ']') from ItemList) as  ItemIds,
    '2024-10-23' AS Created,
    111 AS SiteId,
    2 AS PriorityLevel
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;

And that gave me the desired output:
{"CategoryId":100,"AccountId":200,"ItemIds":[12,13,14,15],"Created":"2024-10-23","SiteId":111,"PriorityLevel":2}

